# Facebook, Twitter Integration with Phonegap Application without using Plugins

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, plugins, twitter

I'm developing a **Phonegap Application** for multiple platforms.

My need is to integrate **Social Sites (Facebook & Twitter)**.

I can integrate by using **Plugins**, but I don't want to use **Plugins** for these because I have to create plugins for different versions too.

So any idea to integrate **Javascript** code for phonegap application for these features, so we can easily work with multiple platforms by using single **HTML, Javascript** file.

Need this answer urgently.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the Javascript API from Facebook: [Click here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)
2. Use the jQuery API for Twitter: [Click Here](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-twitter-api/)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any examples for it ?